# Lift of the Abel-Jacobi map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth complex surface of genus $g$, we denote by $p_{\infty}$ its point at infinity. There is a set of loops $(a_{1}, \dots, a_{g}, b_{1}, \dots b_{g})$ and a basis $(\omega_{1}, \dots , \omega_{g})$ in the space of holomorphic differentials such that
$$
\int_{a_{i}}\omega_{j}=\delta_{ij}.
$$
The period matrix $\Omega$ of $C$ is defined by

$$
\Omega_{i,j}:=\int_{b_{i}}\omega_{j}
$$

We define the lattice $\Lambda:= \mathbb{Z}^{g}+\Omega\cdot \mathbb{Z}^{g} \subset \mathbb{C}^{g}$. The Abel-Jacobi map is the holomorphic map

$$
J\: : \: X\to \mathbb{C}^{g}/\Lambda
$$

given by $J(q):=\left(\int_{p_{\infty}}^{q}\omega_{1}, \dots, \int_{p_{\infty}}^{q}\omega_{g} \right) $, where the integral is taken over a path connecting $q$ with $p_{\infty}$.  We denote by $\tilde{J}\: : \: \tilde{X}\to \mathbb{C}^{g}$ its lift between universal covers.

Questions:

1) Does exist a explicit description of $\tilde{J}$ (using integrals..)?

2) Is $\tilde{J}$ a holomorphic embedding (like $J$)?

Comment: For $X= X_1(N)$ the modular curve, the cover is from the upper-half plane and $\omega_j = f_j(z)dz$ where $f_j \in S_2(\Gamma_1(N))$ are modular forms.

Comment: Anything unclear ? Thus for $g \ge 2$ the lifts are special holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{H}$ or $\mathbb{D}$

Comment: Is $\tilde{J}$ defined by  integrals (by lifting the path from $p_{\infty}$ to $q$)? Is this map an embedding? If you can write below more details or give a reference will be great :)!

Comment: Sure. Let $\mathbb{H} = \{s \in \mathbb{C},\Im(s) > 0\}$, $\mathbb{H}^* = \mathbb{H}  \cup \mathbb{Q} \cup \{i \infty\}$, $X_1(N)= \mathbb{H}^* / \Gamma_1(N)$. For any basepoint $p \in \mathbb{H}^*$ the Abel-Jacobi map is $\tilde{J} : \mathbb{H}^* \to \mathbb{C}^g, s \mapsto (\int_p^s f_1(z)dz,\ldots,\int_p^s f_g(z)dz)$ where $f_1,\ldots,f_g$ is a basis of [$S_2(\Gamma_1(N))$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form#Modular_forms_for_more_general_groups). It is an holomorphic map and $\tilde{J}( \Gamma_1(N) p) $ is a lattice $\Lambda$.

Comment: Then you need to look at the map $\sum_i p_i - q_i \in Div^0(X) \mapsto \sum_i J(p_i) - J(q_i)$, the hardest part is to show only the divisors of meromorphic functions are sent to $\Lambda$.

Comment: Ok!  It seems to me that $\tilde{J}$ is not an embedding (I need to quotient by the lattice...) right?

Comment: An embedding of what ? $\tilde{J}$ is of course not injective, but it is holomorphic. When quotienting by $\Gamma_1(N)$ and $\Lambda$ it becomes injective.

Comment: Ok got it. Let me summarize. Given a compact Riemann surface of genus $g\geq 2$, then $X=\mathbb{H}/G$, for some fuchsian group $G$. The Abel-Jacobi map can be written as above, where the $f_{i}$ are a basis of $S_{2}(G)$. In particular $\tilde{J}$ is a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{H}$ . This is exaktaly wath I was looking for! Thanks!